# Is it possible to get the object properties of a geometry node parent when shading an instance?

Tags: materials, objects, geometry-nodes, instances

I'm working on a sea anemone, and have an old trick I like to use where I feed an object location (for a static object) into a noise texture to get a hue rotation. In the past, by doing this, I can get new colors for each instance of my object.

However, for the nematocysts (the little tentacles) I'm using geometry nodes, and I've noticed that each instance has its own position being fed into the hue rotation, which is causing unwanted color shifts. (It may be pretty, but it's dead wrong.) Is it possible for me to access the *instance parent's* location in the shader?

I'm guessing the answer is "no" and I'm going to have to apply the geometry node modifier, but I feel I should check because it would save me a world of time.

[image: example of node behavior]
The node's current behavior

[image: corrected model (applied geometry)]
What I would be expecting, but with the geometry nodes applied instead of having them available. Note that as it's moved in object mode, the hue shifts.

Comment: Note that, weirdly, it seems to be working now that I've undone the application of the geometry nodes. That's very strange and a little bug-like. I think the question still stands in principle, though. (Good thing I took a screen shot.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances inside an object are basically separate objects.

Just add **Realize Instances** node at the end of GN tree. This will remove all separate objects and merge them into one.